# When publishing an application to IIS is a port binding necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

On our IIS we have multiple websites that serve shared applications under their respective hostname/bindings...

We achieve this by deploying the applications and then using the "Add Application" so that it can be served as "http://myhost1.com/myAddedApplicationAlias".

This works great, except that when deploying the application to be shared, we have to enter a bogus port number...

How can we avoid this port binding since the added application will be served from an existing web site's hostname/bindings?

Comment: What do you mean by *when deploying the application to be shared*?

Comment: 1. Existing web site at hostame http://existing.com 2. Deploy application 3. In IIS, Right click on existing site, choose "Add Application"

Comment: I use IIS 7.5 and have added an application to an existing website and I do not have to bind that application to a port. And it seems to just use the port to the parent website---so that a new `test` app in `existing.com:88` will just launch the new `test` site/app with the address `existing.com:88/test`. I'm using WebDeploy.